# Deadlock in multi-threaded Windows GUI application

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll, vst

I develop a [DAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) application for Windows 10. It's a x64 application written in C++ and built by Visual Studio 2019.

The application uses a custom GUI that does not use any Windows APIs but it also has to load [VST 2.4 plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) that *do* use standard Win32 GUI and I open them in modeless popup (non-child) windows.

The problem I've been trying to solve is a deadlock -- see below.

Disclaimer: I know the code isn't perfect and optimized -- it's a work in progress please.

```
======== main.cpp =============================

// ...

void winProcMsgRelay ()
{
    MSG     msg;

    CLEAR_STRUCT (msg);

    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL,  0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) 
    { 
        TranslateMessage (&msg);
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
    };
}

// ...

int CALLBACK WinMain (HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdL, int nCmdShw)  
{
// ...
}

=================================================
```

1) The `WinMain` function creates a new thread that will handle our custom GUI (which does not use any Windows API).

2) The **WinMain thread** uses the standard Windows GUI API and it handles all window messages delivered to our main application window.

The **WinMain thread**  creates our main window by calling `CreateWindowEx` (with a `WNDPROC` window procedure callback):

```
{
    WNDCLASSEX  wc;

    window_menu = CreateMenu ();
    if (!window_menu)
    {
        // Handle error
        // ...
    }

    wc.cbSize = sizeof (wc);
    wc.style = CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = mainWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APP);
    wc.hCursor = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = mainWinName;
    wc.lpszClassName = mainWinName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APP);
    RegisterClassEx (&wc);

    mainHwnd = CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP,
                                       mainWinName, mainWinTitle,
                                       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                                       CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
                                       0, 0,
                                       NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);


    // ...

    // Then the WinMain thread keeps executing a standard window message processing loop 

    // ...
    while (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) != 0
           && ! requestQuit)
    {
        if (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0) == 0)
        {
            requestQuit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (! requestQuit)
        {
            WaitMessage ();
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

3) Our **custom-GUI thread** (spawned above), in addition to its other functions, does the following:

a) Loads a VST audio plugin from a DLL file by calling `LoadLibrary`.

b) Creates a new thread for the DLL plugin (let's call it "**plugin thread**") to create a new instance of it (there may be multiple instances of a loaded DLL plugin):

```
vst_instance_thread_handle = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex (NULL, _stack_size, redirect, (void *) this, 0, NULL);
```

c) After some time that the plugin instance has been running on its own thread, our **custom-GUI thread** (in response to a user action in our custom GUI) creates a new thread for the plugin GUI window:

```
vst_gui_thread_handle = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex (NULL, _stack_size, redirect, (void *) this, 0, NULL);
```

(Note that the DLL plugin uses standard Win32 GUI.)

When the new **plugin GUI thread** is being spawned, the function `VSTGUI_open_vst_gui` is called on the **plugin instance thread** -- see below:

```
    ============ vst_gui.cpp: ====================

// ...

struct VSTGUI_DLGTEMPLATE: DLGTEMPLATE
{
    WORD e[3];
    VSTGUI_DLGTEMPLATE ()
    {
        memset (this, 0, sizeof (*this));
    };
};

static INT_PTR CALLBACK VSTGUI_editor_proc_callback (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

thread_local AEffect * volatile Vst_instance_ptr = 0;
thread_local volatile int Vst_instance_index = -1;
thread_local volatile UINT_PTR Vst_timer_id_ptr = 0;
thread_local volatile HWND Vst_gui_handle = NULL;

void VSTGUI_open_vst_gui (int vst_instance_index)
{
    AEffect *vst_instance = VST_instances [vst_instance_index].vst->pEffect;

    Vst_instance_index = vst_instance_index;
    Vst_instance_ptr = vst_instance;

    VSTGUI_DLGTEMPLATE t;   

    t.style = WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_VISIBLE |
                          DS_MODALFRAME | DS_CENTER;

    t.cx = 100; // We will set an appropriate size later
    t.cy = 100;


    VST_instances [vst_instance_index].vst_gui_open_flag = false;

    Vst_gui_handle = CreateDialogIndirectParam (GetModuleHandle (0), &t, 0, (DLGPROC) VSTGUI_editor_proc_callback, (LPARAM) vst_instance);

    if (Vst_gui_handle == NULL)
    {
        // Handle error
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // Wait for the window to actually open and initialize -- that will set the vst_gui_open_flag to true
        while (!VST_instances [vst_instance_index].vst_gui_open_flag)
        {
            winProcMsgRelay ();
            Sleep (1);
        }

        // Loop here processing window messages (if any), because otherwise (1) VST GUI window would freeze and (2) the GUI thread would immediately terminate.
        while (VST_instances [vst_instance_index].vst_gui_open_flag)
        {
            winProcMsgRelay ();
            Sleep (1);
        }
    }

    // The VST GUI thread is about to terminate here -- let's clean up after ourselves
    // ...
    return;
}



// The plugin GUI window messages are handled by this function:

INT_PTR CALLBACK VSTGUI_editor_proc_callback (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    AEffect* vst_instance = Vst_instance_ptr;
    int instance_index = Vst_instance_index;

    if (VST_instances [instance_index].vst_gui_window_handle == (HWND) INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        VST_instances [instance_index].vst_gui_window_handle = hwnd;
    }

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            SetWindowText (hwnd, String (tmp_str) + VST_get_best_vst_name (instance_index, false));

            if (vst_instance)
            {
                ERect* eRect = 0;
                vst_instance->dispatcher (vst_instance, effEditGetRect, 0, 0, &eRect, 0);

                if (eRect)
                {
                    // ...

                    SetWindowPos (hwnd, HWND_TOP, x, y, width, height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                }

                vst_instance->dispatcher (vst_instance, effEditOpen, 0, 0, hwnd, 0);
            }
        }   
        VST_instances [instance_index].vst_gui_open_flag = true;

        if (SetTimer (hwnd, (UINT_PTR) Vst_instance_ptr, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            logf ("Error: Could not obtain a timer object for external VST GUI editor window.\n");  
        }

        return 1; 

    case    WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);
            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_MOVE:

        if (Vst_instance_index >= 0)
        {
            VST_instances [Vst_instance_index].vst_gui_win_pos_x = VST_get_vst_gui_win_pos_x (Vst_instance_index);
            VST_instances [Vst_instance_index].vst_gui_win_pos_y = VST_get_vst_gui_win_pos_y (Vst_instance_index);
        }

        return 0; 

    case WM_SIZE:

        if (Vst_instance_index >= 0)
        {
            VST_instances [Vst_instance_index].vst_gui_win_width = VST_get_vst_gui_win_width (Vst_instance_index);
            VST_instances [Vst_instance_index].vst_gui_win_height = VST_get_vst_gui_win_height (Vst_instance_index);
        }

        return 0; 

    case WM_TIMER:

        if (vst_instance != NULL)
        {
            vst_instance->dispatcher (vst_instance, effEditIdle, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_CLOSE:

        // ...

        return 0; 

    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        return 0;

    default:
        return (DefWindowProc (hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
    }

        return 0;
=================================================
```

Our **custom-GUI thread**, too, periodically calls `winProcMsgRelay (); Sleep (1);` in a loop.

Why multi-threaded? Because: 1) this is a real-time audio-processing application where near-zero latencies are required, and 2) we need to set CPU priorities and stack sizes independently for each thread, based on their real needs. Also, 3) having multi-threaded GUI allows our DAW app to remain responsive when the plugin or its GUI becomes unresponsive and 4) we make us of multi-core CPUs.

**Everything is working well.** I can open multiple instances of multiple plugins. Their GUI windows **can even spawn other windows** showing progress bars, all that ***without* any deadlock**.

However, the problem is that I get a deadlock when I click the app logo in a plugin GUI window (Absynth 5 and Kontakt 6 by Native Instruments), which apparently **creates a child modal window**, which, by the way, displays correctly and fully. 
But both this modal window and the parent GUI window stop responding to user actions and window messages -- they "hang" (our custom GUI keeps working well, though). The same thing happens when the plugin GUI displays a standard Windows modal **MessageBox** on error, where the MessageBox is completely "frozen".

When I set a debugger breakpoint in `VSTGUI_open_vst_gui` in the second loop that calls `winProcMsgRelay`, **I can determine that this is the place where it hangs**, because when I get the deadlock state, that **breakpoint is never triggered**.

I know that modal dialogs have their own message loop that might block ours, but how should I redesign my code to accommodate for that?

I also know that `SendMessage` and the like are blocking until they get response. That's why I use the asynchronous `PostMessage`, instead.

I confirmed that the deadlock occurs in 32-bit builds of the application, too.

I've been trying to trace the cause for several weeks. I believe I've done all my homework and I honestly don't know what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to make multi threaded UI?

Comment: Your "standard message loop" is pretty non-standard. Why are you calling `PeekMessage` and then `GetMessage` ? If there's no message in the queue when you call `PeekMessage` it'll return false and your message loop will exit at that point.

Comment: @JonathanPotter No, the loop will exit only when we set requestQuit to true based on user action or when we receive a standard quit event. It's tested and it works, believe me. And why PeekMessage? From MS docs: The main difference between the two functions is that GetMessage does not return until a message matching the filter criteria is placed in the queue, whereas PeekMessage returns immediately regardless of whether a message is in the queue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not sure what you mean, but the application uses many independent GUIs, some custom (host), some Windows-based (main window app, and dplugins).

Comment: And custom GUI is used to keep the DAW application portable to non-Windows operating systems .Also, the PeekMessage-GetMessage loop in the WinMain thread is not hanging -- I verified that in debugger, as I wrote. That's not the culprit. Finally, please read the disclaimer at the beginning of my post.

Comment: As Joe suggests in his answer below. What does the callstack look like of all thread when you break into the debugger upon hitting a frozen ui scenario?

Comment: @deLock `PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) != 0 && ! requestQuit` - the loop will exit if `PeekMessage` returns 0.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I see now what happened. The code I quoted from my source code was not complete. That loop is surrounded by code that keeps the loop going. It is a tested working code, but it was quoted incompletely, so you could not see it. I've edited the text to make it clear -- surrounded the loop with // ...

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to resolve the deadlock myself -- see my answer to my own post. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to resolve the deadlock myself. The solution was to rewrite the code so as to unify the window proc handlers (VST GUI messages are handled by the same callback function as the main window messages). Moreover, unlike the official VST SDK, which uses DialogBoxIndirectParam to create the plugin window, I now use CreateWindowEx, instead (not sure if this contributed to solving the deadlock issue, though). Thanks for the comments.

Comment: It's hard to see how this could be much use to future readers, since it is so specific to your own code, which we can't see. If I were you I would remove the entire post.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Honestly, I don't see anything that would make it specific to my code. But most importantly, someone could design their program in a similar way and encounter the same issue. If they follow my solution, I don't see why it shouldn't help them.

Comment: How would anybody know if their issue was the same as yours? There isn't a clear reproduction, just a description which is presumably missing important details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of code not appearing here (e.g. winProcMsgRelay) and I will admit I'm finding it difficult to get a mental picture of how this works, but let me offer you some general advice and some things to keep in mind.

First of all, modal dialogs have their own message loop.  As long as they are up, your message loop will not run.

Second of all, windows functions like SetWindowPos SetWindowText actually ***send a message*** to the window.  Are you calling those from the thread that that created the window?  Because if not, that means that the calling thread will block while the OS sends the message to the window and waits for a response.   If the thread that created those windows is busy, the sending thread will remain blocked until it is not.

If I were attempting to debug this, I would simply wait until it deadlocks, then break into the debugger and bring up the threads and call stacks windows next to each other.   Switch context among the threads in the threads windows (double click on them) and look at the resulting thread call stacks.  You should be able to spot the problem.

Comment: The full code for winProcMsgRelay is actually is at the top of my post. I can also post more code if needed. Just tell me. I know modal dialogs have their own message loop, but how should I redesign my code to accommodate for that? I also know that SendMessage and the like are blocking until they get response. That's why I use the async PostMessage instead. Lastly, the debugger pause advice I already did, as I wrote, and so I know where the deadlock is. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have solved it but I want to reply in the event you hit this again.  Sorry I missed winProcMsgRelay but in your post it is missing the first line (the title!) so I couldn't see that.   Also, while using PostMessage is nice, you are also using SetWindowPos and SetWindowText and those calls do *not* post their messages.  They block.  Are those calls happening from the threads that created those windows?  Finally, I think that the way to redesign is to keep all windows in one UI thread and not have any background threads wait on them.  Multiple UI threads is not the way to go